# What happens to the processor after a breakpoint is hit?

Tags: x86, arm, cpu-architecture, breakpoints

I was reading up about breakpoints from a few articles such as this: https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/cortex-m-breakpoints

Most resources mention that the processor gets halted. What does a processor halt mean? The processor would still be getting clock input right? If so, it should ideally start fetching and executing the next instruction. However, that does not happen.

So, can anyone help me understand what happens to the processor when a break point is hit?

Comment: the link you provided is quite clear, what part do you not understand?

Comment: the clock through the system does not stop.  But the logic stops fetching and/or it triggers some form of exception which may or may not have an exception handler, since you taggeed this as x86 and arm, implies you want to know in general and in general different processors work in different ways.  Also the link talks about hardware and software breakpoints, which again, can be done in different ways depending on the architecture and the type of breakpoint or inserted instruction.

Comment: processors are not constantly fetching and executing instructions, you understand this yes?  they can up to a point but if there are memory accesses, which can take dozens to hundreds of clock cycles, the processor will stop fetching and executing until that access finishes and the instruction that caused it can continue.   this is no different it simply stops fetching and execution, and/or redirects it like an exception or interrupt depending on the architecture and type of breakpoint solution.

Comment: since the link identifies cortex-m you can also have WFE or WFI, which on some cortex-ms is just a nop and on others actuall will wait for an exection or an interrupt. also halting the execution and fetching of instructions until an exception or interrupt happens.   (and also possibly putting the mcu/core in a low power state, but that is also more reading that you need to do from the chip (not arm) documentation)

Comment: Hi @old_timer
The link mentions the following: " When the instructions match, the hardware will trigger a debug event, halting the core or generating an exception". My question is what happens when a CPU is halted? What does a halt mean? Doe that mean the CPU no longer receives clock input? If the CPU is still getting clocked, then it should proceed to execute the next instruction right? 
However, that does not happen until we manually "resume" debugging by selecting the resume icon.

I am referring to hardware breakpoints in specific.

Comment: no, I answered that allready, the clocks do not stop on a processor.   Clocks are used by all of the logic not just the fetch and execution units.  the processor will continue to consume clocks and look at the signals that indicate halt or not, if the signals indicate halt then it does not fetch or execute (if halted, if instead it causes an exception then it executes the code in the exception handler)

Comment: being clocked does not mean constant fetching and execution, be it a halt, breakpoint, memory access, wait for exception, etc.   there is not a one to one relation ship to the clock and the fetching and execution of instructions.

Comment: just like writing software, with if-then-else.  If the pipe is full or if the pipe is halted or if the instruction is a wait for interrupt, etc, then each clock cycle it will re-examine these states to determine if it can then fetch again.

Comment: if my fetch has not come back with new instructions then I have to wait and you can certainly see this on microcontrollers, the flash is usually slower than the processor so it may only be able to decode instructions every other or every three or four or several clock cycles and be stalled in between.

Comment: clock gating is generally not used for this.  It may be used for low power modes which is a whole other deal.  but stopping the fetching/execution/pipe is generally done through signals into the state machine and not through clock gating.   the clock keeps running and the state machine works through the states each clock.  and there are different states that can stall or halt a processor....again in an mcu like this it is stalling all the time just trying to fetch instructions because the flash and the peripherals are clocked slower than the processor. not a one to one thing clock to execution

Comment: "if my fetch ha not come back with new instructions then I have to wait". What does the wait here mean? That the CPU is executing NOP instruction?

Comment: it is not executing any instructions, it is stopped/halted/stalled.  no fetching no instructions, clock is running the state machine and the state machine says the processor is stopped,  halted, stalled, whatever term makes sense to you

Comment: If I stop my car at a light, the car is on, the engine is running, but the car is not moving.  if I stop the processor everything is powered and clocked and working but it is in a stopped state, no fetching, no executing.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: there are many open source processors out there that you can examine the code, verilog looks a lot like C and you can examine all the if-then-elses in there to see how this all works, it is as simple as writing software with if-then-elses, not all code paths run each time through the function

Comment: the fact that the debugger can talk to the processor and read register values and the processor state means the processor is being clocked.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, @old_timer.

Comment: On most multitasking systems, its the process that gets stopped, not the processor.  The processor goes on to run something else, like the debugger.

Comment: sure and that is the case where an exception or some other code path is taken rather than that processor actually stopping on that instruction.   like a breakpoint in the cortex-m going to the hardfault.  something has to tell the operating system that the process has stopped on an instruction indefinitely and that it can use the processor for something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not confuse the clocking of a processor or any logic and fetch and execution.  There is a disconnect between each clock and each fetch and execute.  All of the processor is clocked not just the actual state machine that does the fetch, decode, execute, etc.  The clock feeds memory interfaces, many of the signals and registers and such are clocked, there is some form of processor bus that runs off the clock, a debug interface is clocked, etc.

Other than some low power modes we will not get into, the clock to the processor is not gated (like the gate around my yard, can be open or closed allowing people through or not)(the clock can be blocked or not).  Clock gating is not used for breakpoint or halting in general, these are just inputs to the state machine that runs the processor.  (google state machine or finite state machine).

You may already know from textbook processors (fetch, decode, execute, writeback, ...)(which to some extent are not exactly how they are implemented outside the classroom, it is just a textbook understanding) that the processor may stall the pipeline.  There are names for the reasons to stall, but this is another example where there is a disconnect between fetch/execute and the processors clock.  The processor clock will keep going but the processor does not actually fetch and/nor execute.  Usually this is temporary.  In an MCU like the cortex-m family described in your external reference.  You normally execute instructions from flash, and you normally talk to peripherals.  It is very common for the flash to be running on a clock that is half or some other multiple slower than the processor clock.  And for many if you push the processor clock faster with a pll there may be rules that the peripheral clock has to be slower.  And no reason to assume that a bus transaction to a peripheral at the same clock rate or slower happens in one clock, it does not.  Many of the cortex-m cores fetch either 16 or 32 bits at a time per fetch (bus) cycle.  If the flash is say half the clock rate of the processor and it is fetching a halfword at a time, then the processor can only fetch one instruction every two clock cycles.  And thus can execute no more than one instruction every two clock cycles as well, but is slower a lot of the time.  Likewise if it takes say 8 clock cycles to read the status of the uart, then that one execution state of the LDR reading that address stalls the processor at least 8 clocks.  Some prefetching may be in flight as well as some decoding but the execution stage is stalled and eventually the whole processor stalls.   halts and breakpoints are no different, except that the processor never leaves the "execution" state.  Or at least on its own.  As shown with the debugger, there are signals that the human can interact with using the debugger that can kick the processor out of that execution state into other states (perhaps fetching from a new address or just moving it out of the execution state into the next state).

So as an example let us make a simple cortex-m simulator, that only knows about a few instructions.  It is not a parallel pipeline (and some of these cortex-ms have very few states in their pipe, not even enough for all the textbook states) but a serial execution, perhaps the thing you do in that college course before you move on to a parallel pipe.  This could be optimized more, but it is intentionally broken into a number of states, and does to some extent one thing per clock.

Some processors implement general purpose registers such that each register is its own chunk of flip flops and multiple registers can be accessed in one clock, for demonstration purposes mine is going to be a register file, a.k.a, sram.  And single ported so that only one thing can happen at time, one read or one write.   So if I want to do an add r0,r1,r2, then it takes a whole clock to get the value r2 from the register file, a whole separate clock to get r1, and a whole separate clock to write r0 (after adding).

I am going to cheat a little here and there.  I could go through the states it takes to do a reset, which for a cortex-m involves at a minimum reading the word at address 0x00000000 and the word at address 0x00000004 (note some folks think instructions do this, no just logic, instructions are a concept that the logic operates on just like words on this page are something that mean something to us, but are built out of individual letters of the alphabet and displayed using many pixels.  These reads of memory are likely separate bus cycles just to get the stack pointer init value and the reset exception handler address.  So I cheated there, also I made my memory 16 bit wide not 32 nor 64, etc.  Makes the code a bit easier to read.

My program under test is

```
.thumb
.cpu cortex-m0

.word 0x20001000
.word reset
.thumb_func
reset:
    add r1,#1
    add r2,#2
    add r1,r1,r2
    add r1,r1,r1
    add r1,#3
    add r1,#4
    add r1,#5
    add r1,#6
    bkpt
    add r1,#7
    add r1,#8
    add r1,#9
    add r1,#10
    b .
```

And here is my state machine based processor in C

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned short mem[256];
unsigned int reg[16];
unsigned int pc;
unsigned int pc_next;
unsigned int state;
unsigned int next_state;
unsigned int alu_a;
unsigned int alu_b;
unsigned int alu_out;
unsigned int rd;
unsigned int rn;
unsigned int rm;
unsigned int imm;
unsigned short inst;

unsigned int print_breakpoint_flag;

enum
{
    NONE,
    FETCH,
    DECODE,
    ADD_IMM,
    ADD_REG_A,
    ADD_REG_B,
    ADD_EXECUTE,
    ADD_WRITEBACK,
    BREAKPOINT
};

void reset ( void )
{
    //normally this is assumed to be random garbage not zeros;
    memset(reg,0,sizeof(reg));
    //this would normally be done in the state machine as well with
    //some number of clock cycles
    reg[13]=mem[1];
    reg[13]<<=16;
    reg[13]|=mem[0];
    pc_next=mem[3];
    pc_next<<=16;
    pc_next|=mem[2];
    if((pc_next&1)==0)
    {
        printf("thumb only\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pc_next&=(~1);
    printf("RESET 0x%08X 0x%08X\n",reg[13],pc_next);
    next_state=FETCH;
}

void one_clock ( void )
{
    state=next_state;
    next_state=NONE;
    switch(state)
    {
        case FETCH:
        {
            printf("FETCH 0x%08X\n",pc_next);
            pc=pc_next;
            pc_next=pc+2;
            reg[15]=pc+4;
            inst=mem[pc>>1];
            next_state=DECODE;
            print_breakpoint_flag=1;
            break;
        }
        case DECODE:
        {
            printf("DECODE 0x%04X\n",inst);
            if((inst&0xF800)==0x3000)
            {
                //add immediate immed8
                rd=(inst>>8)&0x7;
                rn=rd;
                imm=(inst>>0)&0xFF;
                next_state=ADD_IMM;
            }
            if((inst&0xFE00)==0x1800)
            {
                rd=(inst>>0)&7;
                rn=(inst>>3)&7;
                rm=(inst>>6)&7;
                next_state=ADD_REG_A;
                break;
            }
            if((inst&0xFF00)==0xBE00)
            {
                imm=(inst>>0)&0xFF;
                next_state=BREAKPOINT;
            }
            break;
        }
        case ADD_IMM:
        {
            printf("ADD_IMM r%u #0x%X\n",rn,imm);
            alu_a=reg[rn];
            alu_b=imm;
            next_state=ADD_EXECUTE;
            break;
        }
        case ADD_EXECUTE:
        {
            printf("ADD_EXECUTE 0x%08X 0x%08X\n",alu_a,alu_b);
            alu_out=alu_a+alu_b;
            //not doing flags
            next_state=ADD_WRITEBACK;
            break;
        }
        case ADD_WRITEBACK:
        {
            printf("ADD_WRITEBACK r%u 0x%08X\n",rd,alu_out);
            reg[rd]=alu_out;
            next_state=FETCH;
            break;
        }
        case ADD_REG_A:
        {
            printf("ADD_REG_A r%u\n",rn);
            alu_a=reg[rn];
            next_state=ADD_REG_B;
            break;
        }
        case ADD_REG_B:
        {
            printf("ADD_REG_B r%u\n",rm);
            alu_b=reg[rm];
            next_state=ADD_EXECUTE;
            break;
        }
        case BREAKPOINT:
        {
            if(print_breakpoint_flag)
            {
                printf("BREAKPOINT\n");
                print_breakpoint_flag=0;
            }
            //some debugger hardware would be implemented to 
            //kick the state machine out of this state.
            next_state=BREAKPOINT;
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }


}

int main ( void )
{

//00000000 <reset-0x8>:
    mem[1]=0x2000; mem[0]=0x1000;//0:   20001000    .word   0x20001000
    mem[3]=0x0000; mem[2]=0x0009;//4:   00000009    .word   0x00000009
//00000008 <reset>:
    mem[ 4]=0x3101; //   8:   3101        adds    r1, #1
    mem[ 5]=0x3202; //   a:   3202        adds    r2, #2
    mem[ 6]=0x1889; //   c:   1889        adds    r1, r1, r2
    mem[ 7]=0x1849; //   e:   1849        adds    r1, r1, r1
    mem[ 8]=0x3103;//1  10:   3103        adds    r1, #3
    mem[ 9]=0x3104;//1  12:   3104        adds    r1, #4
    mem[10]=0x3105;//1  14:   3105        adds    r1, #5
    mem[11]=0x3106;//1  16:   3106        adds    r1, #6
    mem[12]=0xbe00;//1  18:   be00        bkpt    0x0000
    mem[13]=0x3107;//1  1a:   3107        adds    r1, #7
    mem[14]=0x3108;//1  1c:   3108        adds    r1, #8
    mem[15]=0x3109;//1  1e:   3109        adds    r1, #9
    mem[16]=0x310a;//2  20:   310a        adds    r1, #10
    mem[17]=0xe7fe;//2  22:   e7fe        b.n 22 <reset+0x1a>

    reset();
    while(1)
    {
        one_clock();
    }
    return(0);
}
```

The processor clock runs forever, no matter what

```
    while(1)
    {
        one_clock();
    }
```

I did not deal with the flags that an add does, I am not doing any conditional execution, in the few instructions I supported, this is not a complete processor obviously this is just the minimum brute force code to handle a few instructions.

The output of the program looks like this

```
RESET 0x20001000 0x00000008
FETCH 0x00000008
DECODE 0x3101
ADD_IMM r1 #0x1
ADD_EXECUTE 0x00000000 0x00000001
ADD_WRITEBACK r1 0x00000001
FETCH 0x0000000A
DECODE 0x3202
ADD_IMM r2 #0x2
ADD_EXECUTE 0x00000000 0x00000002
ADD_WRITEBACK r2 0x00000002
FETCH 0x0000000C
DECODE 0x1889
ADD_REG_A r1
ADD_REG_B r2
ADD_EXECUTE 0x00000001 0x00000002
ADD_WRITEBACK r1 0x00000003
FETCH 0x0000000E
DECODE 0x1849
ADD_REG_A r1
ADD_REG_B r1
ADD_EXECUTE 0x00000003 0x00000003
ADD_WRITEBACK r1 0x00000006
FETCH 0x00000010
DECODE 0x3103
ADD_IMM r1 #0x3
ADD_EXECUTE 0x00000006 0x00000003
ADD_WRITEBACK r1 0x00000009
FETCH 0x00000012
DECODE 0x3104
ADD_IMM r1 #0x4
ADD_EXECUTE 0x00000009 0x00000004
ADD_WRITEBACK r1 0x0000000D
FETCH 0x00000014
DECODE 0x3105
ADD_IMM r1 #0x5
ADD_EXECUTE 0x0000000D 0x00000005
ADD_WRITEBACK r1 0x00000012
FETCH 0x00000016
DECODE 0x3106
ADD_IMM r1 #0x6
ADD_EXECUTE 0x00000012 0x00000006
ADD_WRITEBACK r1 0x00000018
FETCH 0x00000018
DECODE 0xBE00
BREAKPOINT
```

Each line a clock, a state in the state machine, except at the end, instead of printing BREAKPOINT infinitely I only print it once.

And hopefully this demonstrates the question.

```c
    case BREAKPOINT:
    {
        next_state=BREAKPOINT;
        break;
    }
```

The processor is being clocked, the clock does not stop, the state machine is stuck in the breakpoint state forever.

In a real processor there would be a way out, some other signals also clocked by the processor but not in this state machine but other state machines (remember unlike a C program, things happen in parallel, to demonstrate that one_clock would have multiple state machines or other individual signals)

a little google and some code from stackoverflow

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <termios.h>

unsigned short mem[256];
unsigned int reg[16];
unsigned int pc;
unsigned int pc_next;
unsigned int state;
unsigned int next_state;
unsigned int alu_a;
unsigned int alu_b;
unsigned int alu_out;
unsigned int rd;
unsigned int rn;
unsigned int rm;
unsigned int imm;
unsigned short inst;

unsigned int print_breakpoint_flag;
unsigned int exit_breakpoint;

enum
{
    NONE,
    FETCH,
    DECODE,
    ADD_IMM,
    ADD_REG_A,
    ADD_REG_B,
    ADD_EXECUTE,
    ADD_WRITEBACK,
    BREAKPOINT
};

void reset ( void )
{
    //normally this is assumed to be random garbage not zeros;
    memset(reg,0,sizeof(reg));
    //this would normally be done in the state machine as well with
    //some number of clock cycles
    reg[13]=mem[1];
    reg[13]<<=16;
    reg[13]|=mem[0];
    pc_next=mem[3];
    pc_next<<=16;
    pc_next|=mem[2];
    if((pc_next&1)==0)
    {
        printf("thumb only\r\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pc_next&=(~1);
    printf("RESET 0x%08X 0x%08X\r\n",reg[13],pc_next);
    next_state=FETCH;
}

void one_clock ( void )
{
    state=next_state;
    next_state=NONE;
    switch(state)
    {
        case FETCH:
        {
            printf("FETCH 0x%08X\r\n",pc_next);
            pc=pc_next;
            pc_next=pc+2;
            reg[15]=pc+4;
            inst=mem[pc>>1];
            next_state=DECODE;
            print_breakpoint_flag=1;
            break;
        }
        case DECODE:
        {
            printf("DECODE 0x%04X\r\n",inst);
            if((inst&0xF800)==0x3000)
            {
                //add immediate immed8
                rd=(inst>>8)&0x7;
                rn=rd;
                imm=(inst>>0)&0xFF;
                next_state=ADD_IMM;
            }
            if((inst&0xFE00)==0x1800)
            {
                rd=(inst>>0)&7;
                rn=(inst>>3)&7;
                rm=(inst>>6)&7;
                next_state=ADD_REG_A;
                break;
            }
            if((inst&0xFF00)==0xBE00)
            {
                imm=(inst>>0)&0xFF;
                next_state=BREAKPOINT;
            }
            break;
        }
        case ADD_IMM:
        {
            printf("ADD_IMM r%u #0x%X\r\n",rn,imm);
            alu_a=reg[rn];
            alu_b=imm;
            next_state=ADD_EXECUTE;
            break;
        }
        case ADD_EXECUTE:
        {
            printf("ADD_EXECUTE 0x%08X 0x%08X\r\n",alu_a,alu_b);
            alu_out=alu_a+alu_b;
            //not doing flags
            next_state=ADD_WRITEBACK;
            break;
        }
        case ADD_WRITEBACK:
        {
            printf("ADD_WRITEBACK r%u 0x%08X\r\n",rd,alu_out);
            reg[rd]=alu_out;
            next_state=FETCH;
            break;
        }
        case ADD_REG_A:
        {
            printf("ADD_REG_A r%u\r\n",rn);
            alu_a=reg[rn];
            next_state=ADD_REG_B;
            break;
        }
        case ADD_REG_B:
        {
            printf("ADD_REG_B r%u\r\n",rm);
            alu_b=reg[rm];
            next_state=ADD_EXECUTE;
            break;
        }
        case BREAKPOINT:
        {
            if(print_breakpoint_flag)
            {
                printf("BREAKPOINT\r\n");
                print_breakpoint_flag=0;
            }
            //some debugger hardware would be implemented to 
            //kick the state machine out of this state.
            next_state=BREAKPOINT;
            if(exit_breakpoint)
            {
                exit_breakpoint=0;
                next_state=FETCH;
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }


}



struct termios orig_termios;

void reset_terminal_mode()
{
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &orig_termios);
}

void set_conio_terminal_mode()
{
    struct termios new_termios;

    /* take two copies - one for now, one for later */
    tcgetattr(0, &orig_termios);
    memcpy(&new_termios, &orig_termios, sizeof(new_termios));

    /* register cleanup handler, and set the new terminal mode */
    atexit(reset_terminal_mode);
    cfmakeraw(&new_termios);
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_termios);
}

int kbhit()
{
    struct timeval tv = { 0L, 0L };
    fd_set fds;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(0, &fds);
    return select(1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0;
}

int getch()
{
    int r;
    unsigned char c;
    if ((r = read(0, &c, sizeof(c))) < 0) {
        return r;
    } else {
        return c;
    }
}

int main ( void )
{

//00000000 <reset-0x8>:
    mem[1]=0x2000; mem[0]=0x1000;//0:   20001000    .word   0x20001000
    mem[3]=0x0000; mem[2]=0x0009;//4:   00000009    .word   0x00000009
//00000008 <reset>:
    mem[ 4]=0x3101; //   8:   3101        adds    r1, #1
    mem[ 5]=0x3202; //   a:   3202        adds    r2, #2
    mem[ 6]=0x1889; //   c:   1889        adds    r1, r1, r2
    mem[ 7]=0x1849; //   e:   1849        adds    r1, r1, r1
    mem[ 8]=0x3103;//1  10:   3103        adds    r1, #3
    mem[ 9]=0x3104;//1  12:   3104        adds    r1, #4
    mem[10]=0x3105;//1  14:   3105        adds    r1, #5
    mem[11]=0x3106;//1  16:   3106        adds    r1, #6
    mem[12]=0xbe00;//1  18:   be00        bkpt    0x0000
    mem[13]=0x3107;//1  1a:   3107        adds    r1, #7
    mem[14]=0x3108;//1  1c:   3108        adds    r1, #8
    mem[15]=0x3109;//1  1e:   3109        adds    r1, #9
    mem[16]=0x310a;//2  20:   310a        adds    r1, #10
    mem[17]=0xe7fe;//2  22:   e7fe        b.n 22 <reset+0x1a>

    set_conio_terminal_mode();
    exit_breakpoint=0;
    reset();
    while(1)
    {

        if(kbhit())
        {
            getch();
            exit_breakpoint=1;
        }

        one_clock();
    }
    return(0);
}
```

At least on my linux system, I can now run it, it "halts" at the breakpoint, until I press a key on the keyboard, and then it continues.

```c
    case BREAKPOINT:
    {
        if(print_breakpoint_flag)
        {
            printf("BREAKPOINT\r\n");
            print_breakpoint_flag=0;
        }
        //some debugger hardware would be implemented to 
        //kick the state machine out of this state.
        next_state=BREAKPOINT;
        if(exit_breakpoint)
        {
            exit_breakpoint=0;
            next_state=FETCH;
        }
        break;
    }

BREAKPOINT
FETCH 0x0000001A
DECODE 0x3107
ADD_IMM r1 #0x7
ADD_EXECUTE 0x00000018 0x00000007
ADD_WRITEBACK r1 0x0000001F
FETCH 0x0000001C
DECODE 0x3108
ADD_IMM r1 #0x8
ADD_EXECUTE 0x0000001F 0x00000008
ADD_WRITEBACK r1 0x00000027
FETCH 0x0000001E
DECODE 0x3109
ADD_IMM r1 #0x9
ADD_EXECUTE 0x00000027 0x00000009
ADD_WRITEBACK r1 0x00000030
FETCH 0x00000020
DECODE 0x310A
ADD_IMM r1 #0xA
ADD_EXECUTE 0x00000030 0x0000000A
ADD_WRITEBACK r1 0x0000003A
FETCH 0x00000022
DECODE 0xE7FE
```

And we see the rest of the execution up to the branch to self, which I did not implement, so it hits the NONE state and exits the program.

In the case of the arm cortex-m family

> Breakpoint causes a HardFault exception or a debug halt to occur depending on the presence and configuration of the debug support.

I have chosen "debug halt" here.  If implemented as a HardFault instead then the processor would not stop execution it would then read the HardFault exception handler address, and then fetch instructions there, as well as all the stack stuff that the processor does to save state before handling the exception.  All of this is to some extent documented in the arm documentation.

The cortex-m and arms in general have WFI as an example which is wait for interrupt

> Wait For Interrupt is a hint instruction that suspends execution until one of a number of events occurs.

And then a page of the documentation goes through the possible ways of getting out of a WFI (if actually implemented, some cores a WFI is just a nop and it does not wait).

A halt if a processor has it would have fewer ways out than a WFI but would be similar to a breakpoint as far as how to get out of it (a reset or some debugger interaction to change the state of the state machine).

Not all processors have a halt.  What I have shown so far is a breakpoint, and while in a ram based system where your program is in ram, as your external documentation states or implies, an instruction would be replaced by a breakpoint.

```
add r1,#4
add r1,#5
add r1,#6
add r3,r3,r1 
add r1,#7
add r1,#8
add r1,#9
add r1,#10
```

you might go into some gui debug tool and select the add r3,r3,r1 and click some breakpoint thing.  That may literally cause the gui software to write a 0xbe00 instruction where that add was, and the software would remember that the add was there.  When you execute, the breakpoint happens, and some debug logic tells the gui (more wires and signals in the processor that the execution of the breakpoint can be detected by the debugger).  When you press some continue button.  The gui will/may replace the breakpoint instruction in that memory location with the real add instruction, and then change the processor state to execute that address again.  That would be the kind of debugger that clears the breakpoint once you stopped on it.  Some may keep that breakpoint and in that case would likely replace the breakpoint with the real instruction, single step, then replace the instruction with the breakpoint then continue execution.

Single stepping with a debugger is just more signals into the processor execution state machine from some some other debugger state machine, to put the processor into a halted state.  state=next_state; if debugger_state=step, then state=WAIT_FOR_STEP. and that wait for step state would wait for some debugger state to change, or some other signal.  (think of signals and registers in logic as variables in C).

The other example of halting on an address, would be in our FETCH state for example

```c
    case FETCH:
    {
        if(pc_next==hardware_monitor_address)
        {
            next_state=HALT;
            break;
        }
        printf("FETCH 0x%08X\r\n",pc_next);
        pc=pc_next;
        pc_next=pc+2;
        reg[15]=pc+4;
```

and that would put us in a halt state similar to the breakpoint and we would need signals from the debugger to kick us out of that state.

Answer (score 0):

> Most resources mention that the processor gets halted. What does a processor halt mean?

"Halted" typically means it's just waiting temporarily.

In this context, it'd mean:

- any "out of order" work will be brought in sync with program order - future work that's being speculatively executed is cancelled, and **the CPU waits for any previous "not finished yet" work to complete/retire**.
- waiting for "address of breakpoint exception vector" to be obtained

After the temporary waiting involved in these 2 things (which likely occur in parallel); the CPU "unhalts", prepares to execute the breakpoint exception handler (e.g. setting up stack frame, etc) and starts executing the breakpoint exception handler.